# Spotify Iframe open a new page or open the app instead of play in the same site

Tags: html, spotify

I have this code in the website

```
<iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify%3Auser%3Ametcastle%3Aplaylist%3A5I28Zby77hlyq61uqfgnZq" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

But when you play the list, open a new page (https://play.spotify.com/) or if you have the app, plays the song in the app.

What I want is hear the music in the same page, i dont want to open a new page or the app!

That is the target of a embed widget right?

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually part of spotify's [widget specifications](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/widgets/spotify-play-button/), it's just how the API works:

> When a logged-in Spotify user clicks the button, the music will start playing in the Spotify player. If the user is not logged into their Spotify account, they will be prompted to do so. If the user does not have a Spotify player they will be sent to the Spotify sign-up page or prompted to download a suitable client, in a new window.

Comment: you can potentially search for a way around it, like other answers are suggesting

Answer (score 1):

Provide an ID to the IFRAME,

`<iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify%3Auser%3Ametcastle%3Aplaylist%3A5I28Zby77hlyq61uqfgnZq" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" id="theFrame"></iframe>`

Use jQuery and target the play element (html component) inside the IFRAME, which mostly should be an anchor tag, `<a>` , set the `target` property of that element to `_self` or '_parent' wherever is best suited for you.

Something like,

`$('document #theFrame #thePlayAnchorTag').attr('target', '_self');`

or,

`$('document #theFrame #thePlayAnchorTag').attr('target', '_parent');`

You got to find out either the class or the id of that play button or some other element which can help you get hold of that play button in jQuery. Try doing a F12, i.e., go to dev tools on the browser and inspect the play button.

Comment: Hi man, thank you you mean like this ?
`<iframe src="xxxxx" id="theFrame"> 
<a href="" target="_self" id="thePlayAnchorTag">Play</a>
</iframe>` not works :(

Comment: @user3810795 You are right with the iframe part. What I additionally added was that, you got to find the play button element within that iframe. It would be a sorta `<a>` tag(probably), and through jQuery you got to set the `target` property to either `_self` or to `_parent`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Doesn't work, I tried that but inside just exists divs without a link <a></a>

Thank you